# Facebook SDK: How to use JavascriptLoginHelper

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, server-communication

I'm implementing a Facebook login flow by using Javascript + PHP SDK. I want to get Access Token from Javascript and pass it to PHP which should extend it (to obtain a long-lived access token) which have to be stored in a Database for making API requests within a month. 
I'm totally new to Web Development, so in order to achieve the result in a limited amount of time I've been going to tons of documentation and tutorials and came up with this two main blocks of code. 
This is my very standard fb-login.js

```
function openWindow(url){
  window.open(url, '_blank');
  window.focus();
}

function statusChangeCallback(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {     //user is authorized
        getUserData();
    } else {  //user is not authorized

    }}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : XXXXXXXXXX,
        xfbml      : true,
        cookie     : true,
        version    : 'v2.2'
    });

    //check user session and refresh it
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};


//load the JavaScript SDK
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

//add event listener to login button
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        //do the login
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                console.log(accessToken);
                getUserData();
                //user just authorized your app               
            }
        }, {scope: 'email,public_profile,user_events,user_videos,user_photos,user_groups,user_friends,user_likes,user_tagged_places,user_actions.books,read_mailbox,read_stream', return_scopes: true});
        //window.location.assign("http://www.giacomogiorgianni.me/questionnaire.html");
    openWindow('//www.giacomogiorgianni.me/questionnaire.html');

    });
});
```

and this is my "login.php" file:

```
require 'fb-php-sdk4/autoload.php'
/* USE NAMESPACES */
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookJavascriptLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;


use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken; 

$app_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXX;
$app_secret= XxXxxxxxxxXXXXxXXXXxxxXXXXxXX;

//Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);

session_start();

//check for existing session and validate it
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
  if (!$session->Validate($app_id, $app_secret)) {
    unset($session);
  }
}

//get new session
if (!isset($session)) {
  try {
    $helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
    $session = $helper->getSession();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $longLivedToken = $token->extend();
  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    unset($session);
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}

if (isset($session)) {
  $me = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', '/me'
  ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
  //$id = $me->getId();
  $name = $me->getName();
  echo $name;
}

// Database connection
$user = "root";
$password = "XXXXXXX";

try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=prova",$user,$password);
    var_dump($db);
    //GGracefully handling Errors
    setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    echo "Connessione riuscita";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Impossibile connettersi al Database /n";
    echo 'E\' stato rilevato il seguente errore: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO prova (id, name, access_token_id) VALUES ($id, $name, $longLivedToken)";
    $db->exec($sql);
    echo "Record inserito nella tabella";
    } catch {
        echo "Impossibile inserire la query";
        echo 'E\' stato rilevato il seguente errore: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
}
    $conn = null;
```

I'm working on a Linux server where I've set LAMP and MySQL and I've got a 'script' folder in which I keep: fb-script.js, login.php and the PHP SDK 4 for Facebook. Outside of this script folder I've got my HTML files.

Now I'd like to point out the following questions:

- I cannot really understand how the javascript sdk and the php are
  bound together? Am I missing anything or there's no evidence they
  have any relationship? Should I insert any AJAX code to pass
  something to the PHP or the Helper is smart enough to handle
  everything ?
- What should I expect to happen SERVER-SIDE when a user click on the
  login button? I know that on javascript everything is working, how can I check on PHP? I tried to look in the database but there was nothing there, so I went on 'myhost.it/script/login.php'. But I only get a blank page. Looking at the console, I have no errors, but when i refresh the page I get "Error 500".
- Can you spot any mistake in my code? I'm note 100% sure of what I'm doing and that's bit frustrating.

I hope I made it clear
Thanks to everyone for your time and effort in reading this and helping me.

Greetings, 
Giacomo

Comment: The only way that the JS SDK and the PHP SDK “work together” is by sharing the cookies set under your domain. And server-side nothing happens when you click the client-side login button – anything you _want_ to happen, you have to implement yourself. // As for your 500 error – only you can investigate where that stems from, so go and take the appropriate steps.

Comment: Yes, once you logged in javascript send an Ajax request to php along with user id and access token. then in php use the same app id and with the access token and user id you received from javascript to request for long lived access token, once you got it, save it to database and send the response back to javascript and do what you want to do parsing the response.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I understand the Data is passed by using the cookies of the session. But the whole process of communication between JS and PHP shouldn't be handled by the JavascriptLoginHelper? Do I still need to pass the token with an AJAX Call?

Comment: I found the issue looking at the error log on the server:

" PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Facebook\\FacebookSession' not found in /var/www/html/script/login.php on line 24 "

Does anyone know why I get this? 
Cheers

Comment: Solved it. I had to replace '/src/Facebook/' with '/src/lib/Facebook/'; in autoload.php. Now everything work fine. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved all my problems so far: 
I didn't need any AJAX POST from Client to Server since JavascriptLoginHelper takes care of all the process.

In order to understand which kind of problems I had on the server (Error 500) I opened up terminal and wrote: ssh server_username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.(host) inserted password and then check the error.log on my server using 'sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log' (My host is DigitalOcean). 
Since then I was able to debug all the problems server-side.

My error was due to the fact that 'autoload.php' has a little bug. Indeed i opened it up and had to replace '/src/Facebook/' with '/src/lib/Facebook/' in autoload.php on line 49. Right now everything works fine.

Thanks you all for your suggestions and hoper this can be useful to someone.

Cheers!